# Count rows for each distinct column values in result set and display zeros

Tags: postgres-12

I have the following table

| name | type | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | student | 2022-10-01 |
| Tom | student | 2022-10-02 |
| Susan | teacher | 2022-10-10 |

I need a query to get the count for each distinct value in type column in filtered result and display zero's if no instances of this type exist in result.

I tried the following

```
SELECT type, COUNT(*)
    FROM tablename
    where created_at between '2022-10-01' and '2022-10-02'
    group by type;
```

which will give

| type | count |
| --- | --- |
| student | 2 |

I need:

| type | count |
| --- | --- |
| student | 2 |
| teacher | 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation with a calendar table approach:

```sql
SELECT t1.type, COUNT(t2.type) AS count
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT type FROM tablename) t1
LEFT JOIN tablename t2
    ON t2.type = t1.type AND
       t2.created_at BETWEEN '2022-10-01' AND '2022-10-02'
GROUP BY t1.type;
```

Note that ideally you should have some other table which stores all types.  Then, you could use that in place of the inline distinct query I have above.